# I want to show zeros in decimal place, but they go away when referenced in SUM

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A1 = 43.00

---

This works:
=SUM(A1) displays 43.00

While this does not:
=SUM(A1)&" Total" displays 43

I would like:
=SUM(A1)&" Total" displays 43.00 Total somehow

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Text()`,

`=Text(Sum(A1),"#0.00")&" Total"`

If `A1` is `1`, this will return `1.00`.
If `A1` is `10`, this will return `10.00`.

If you want `1` to return `01.00`, change the first `#` to a zero in the formula.

Comment: This is the correct method of doing this but you did not answer the OP's other inferred question;  Why does it add the zeros one way but not the other? :)

Comment: @ScottCraner - how should I know how Microsoft thinks :P  ...I'm assuming it removes the zero when adding a string, because it treats the whole cell as TEXT and not a number?

Comment: Yes,  The cell has a number format applied to it so it shows the zeros, but because the `&` concatenates it into a string the number format does not apply.  So one must apply the TEXT() Function to make the string format work.  Another option would have been to apply a number format of `#0.00 \T\o\t\a\l` and the under pinning number would remain accesible for future maths, while showing the text as the OP wanted.

Comment: @ScottCraner - woah woah woah! Can you explain how to set it up so you can still do math on it? Do you just make the format as you described? So if I have a cell with `20` and I want to make that `20 Cars` but still be able to use `Sum()`, `Average()`, etc, would I just set the format of the cell to Custom, `#0.00 \C\a\r\s`? (edit: just saw you posted an answer)

Answer (score 1):

The Text() method given by @BruceWayne is great if you want a text string as your final output.

But if you want to mantaing the ability to do math on that cell while displaying "42.00 Total" The applying a custom number format will work:

```
#0.00 \Total
```

[image]

This will display "42.00 Total" while keeping the actual number 42 as the value of the cell so any math desired does not need to remove the text before using the cell.  As the picture shows: the Cell Displays "42.00 Total" while the formula bar has it as simply 42.

[image]

Comment: Is there any difference in the way you formatted over `"Total" #0.00"`?

Comment: @BruceWayne you can do it that way it is personal preference.  In this instance `#0.00 "Total"` works